# Does the frame package, all are represent as hex data?

Tags: wireshark, data

I use Wireshark for capturing packages, get many frames.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

You see the left light blue background space, all are hex data, and right are converted words we can identify.

I mean whether the frame package itself is hex data? if is which layer convert the characters to the hex data?

Comment: Hint for the future because I saw this error in many Wireshark screen shots: In the screenshot you blacked out the IP address 43.224.xxx.44. But in many screen shorts the HEX data contains the information which is sufficient to reconstruct the blacked-out address.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

Data is binary-ones and zeros. Wireshark displays the data as hex characters so it’s easy to read.